# no me carga el datagrodview en windows form

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, ado.net

Buuenas a toda la comunidad, ha como dos años dejé de programar y estoy retomando nuevamente practicando y desarrollando una aplicación donde hace un CRUD; sin embargo, al buscar un analista en mi BD desde mi aplicativo, no me carga la lista.

Estoy replicando el procedimiento que se realiza al cargar una lista al iniciar el aplicativo, pero para este caso estoy enviando 4.

¿Qué error estoy cometiendo en este método?

El store procedure Buscar analista, si envío parámetros nombre, apellido y correo en vacío y envío un id,me devuelve toda una lista y lo que quiero es que me devuelva solo el registro del id enviado; sin embargo, cuando envío ya sea uno de los parámetros (nombre, apellido o correo) con datos y el id vacío, devolverá una lista de registros.

Por eso me ví en la necesidad de reemplazar los vacíos por un espacio, modificado el store procedure ya me funciona bien, pero al conectar con visual el procedimiento almacenado no me funciona

El caso es que cuando se ingresa el id, solo te debe mostrar un registro, en cambio cuando se ingresa nombre, apellido o correo y se envía el id en null, debe mostrar varios registros
Adjunto los pasos:

Stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROC [dbo].[BuscarAnalista] 
@id int,
@nombre nvarchar(255),
@apellido nvarchar(255),
@correo nvarchar(255)
as
--declare @a nvarchar(255)=' '
if(@nombre='')
begin
set @nombre=' '
end 

if(@apellido='')
begin
set @apellido=' '
end

if(@correo='')
begin
set @correo=' '
end

select * from ANALISTA
where ANA_ID=@id or (ANA_NOM LIKE '%'+@nombre+'%' OR ANA_APE LIKE '%'+@apellido+'%' OR ANA_COR LIKE '%'+@correo+'%')
```

Conexión a la BD - Capa datos

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Datos
{
    public class Conexion
    {
        /*
        private string connectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-CD3131RN;Initial Catalog=PROYECTOS_BANBIF;" +
            "User=usuario01;Password=1234";
        */
        private SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=LAPTOP-CD3131RN;DataBase=PROYECTOS_BANBIF;User=usuario01;Password=1234;Integrated Security=true");

        public SqlConnection abrirConexion()
        {
            if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            
                conexion.Open();
                return conexion;
            

        }

        public SqlConnection cerrarConexion()
        {
            if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            
                conexion.Close();
                return conexion;
            
        }
    }

}
```

Llamada al procedimiento almacenado

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Datos
{
    public class C_ANALISTA
    {
        private Conexion cn = new Conexion();
        SqlDataReader leer;
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();

        //CON ESTE EJEMPLO ME GUIO PARA HACER EL METODO BUSCAR
        public DataTable mostrarListaAnalista()
        {
            comando.Connection = cn.abrirConexion();
            comando.CommandText = "SP_MOSTRAR_ANALISTA";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
            tabla.Load(leer);
            cn.cerrarConexion();
            return tabla;
        }

       //METODO BUSCAR, EL CUAL FALLA

        public DataTable buscarAnalista(int id, string nombre, string apellido, string correo)
        {

            
            comando.Connection = cn.abrirConexion();
            comando.CommandText = "BuscarAnalista";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", apellido);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", correo);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
            tabla.Load(leer);
            cn.cerrarConexion();
            return tabla;
        }
    }
}
```

Capa negocio

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Datos;

namespace Negocio
{
    public class N_ANALISTA
    {
        private C_ANALISTA analistas = new C_ANALISTA();
        
        public DataTable mostrarAnalistas()
        {
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            tabla = analistas.mostrarListaAnalista();
            return tabla;
        }

        public DataTable buscarAnalista(int id, string nombre, string apellido, string correo)
        {
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            tabla = analistas.buscarAnalista(Convert.ToInt32(id),nombre,apellido,correo);
            return tabla;
        }
    }
}
```

Cargar el formulario

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Negocio;


namespace ProyectosBanbif
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        N_ANALISTA objetoN = new N_ANALISTA();
        private string idanalista = null;

        private void MostrarAnalistas()
        {
            N_ANALISTA objeto = new N_ANALISTA();
            dgvAnalistas.DataSource = objeto.mostrarAnalistas();
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MostrarAnalistas();
        }

        private void dgvAnalistas_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtNomAna.Text = dgvAnalistas.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtApeAna.Text = dgvAnalistas.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtCelAna.Text = dgvAnalistas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                txtCorAna.Text = dgvAnalistas.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                idanalista = dgvAnalistas.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void btnBuscarAna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            N_ANALISTA analistaEncontrado = new N_ANALISTA();
            analistaEncontrado.buscarAnalista(Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text),txtNomAna.Text,txtApeAna.Text,txtCorAna.Text);
            dgvAnalistas.DataSource = analistaEncontrado.mostrarAnalistas();
            MostrarAnalistas();
            txtApeAna.Text = "";
            txtNomAna.Text = "";
            txtCelAna.Text = "";
            txtCorAna.Text = "";
            txtId.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ERROR QUE LANZA]

[image: Resultado store procedure]

Comment: En el SP, ¿por qué sustituyes los parámetros en blanco por un espacio?

Comment: buenas amigo, pasa que si envío parametros nombre, apellido y correo en vacío y envío un id,me devuelve toda una lista y lo que quiero es que me devuelva solo el registro del id enviado, sin embargo, cuando envío ya sea uno de los paramtros(nombre, apellido o correo) con datos y el id vacío, devolverá una lista de registros. Por eso me ví en la necesidad de reemplazar los vacíos por un espacio

Comment: Comprendo, el problema está en el SP. Con gusto puedo escribir una respuesta si colocas la información que has comentado como parte de la pregunta. No olvides indicar qué valor utilizas para indicar un _"id vacío"_ (puede ser 0 o null, o quizás un valor negativo... ). Cuándo lo hayas hecho, déjame un comentario. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate acabo de actualizar la pregunta estimado, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Olvidaste decir cuál es tu valor para _id vacío_, que no me queda claro. Ahora que re-leí tu pregunta, también me queda la duda de si hay algún caso donde si funcione, o falla siempre, porque aparte del fallo del SP puede haber otro (en ese caso, habría que ver a cuál te refieres en la pregunta, pues el formato del sitio no es para responder dos preguntas en una sola publicación).

Comment: @jachguate agregué una imagen donde se muestra el resultado del store procedure

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145614/discussion-between-jachguate-and-c-aldair).